# Why my React + Vite build requires nested BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, vite

There are two React + Vite + Typescript applications: `AppOne` and `MainApp`.
The `AppOne` exports its App component. The `MainApp` imports the App component from `AppOne` and renders it on the `/appOne/*` route. The `MainApp` runs on `localhost:3010/` URL.
Here are the `MainApp`'s routes:

```
export function MainAppRoutes() {
return useRoutes([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <MainApp />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/appOne/*",
                element: (
                    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingOverlay />}>
                        <AppOne />
                    </Suspense>
                ),
            },
        ],
    },
]);
};
```

and here are the `AppOne`'s routes:

```
export function AppOneRoutes() {
return useRoutes([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <AppOne />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                element: (
                    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingOverlay />}>
                        <ComponentOne />
                    </Suspense>
                ),
            },
            {
                path: "two",
                element: (
                    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingOverlay />}>
                        <ComponentTwo />
                    </Suspense>
                ),
            },
        ],
    },
]);
};
```

The `AppOne` application has its own wrappers:

```
export function AppOneShell() {
return (
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ReactQueryProvider>
            <ReduxProvider>
                <ErrorBoundary>
                    {/* <BrowserRouter> */}
                        <AppOneRoutes />
                    {/* </BrowserRouter> */}
                </ErrorBoundary>
            </ReduxProvider>
        </ReactQueryProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
};
```

And the `MainApp` app has also its own wrappers:

```
export function MainAppShell() {
return (
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ReactQueryProvider>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <MainAppRoutes />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </ReactQueryProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
};
```

When I run the dev env, it works fine. But when I do `npm run build` and `npm run preview` the `MainApp` is loading but the `AppOne` is not on the `/appOne` URL.
In the browser's console there is an error:

```
Error
at invariant (router.js:270:11)
at useRoutes (index.js:476:77)
at AppOneRoutes (AppOneRoutes.component.tsx:26:9)
```

The interesting part is that when I uncomment `<BrowserRouter>` within the `AppOneShell`, the built version runs without issues. But the dev env is not, since there is `<BrowserRouter>` inside another `<BrowserRouter>`.

Why the build needs the nested `<BrowserRouter>` and how to fix it?

Comment: You need only one router/routing context provider per React app. Where exactly are `MainAppShell` and `AppOneShell` being rendered? Can you [edit] to include a more complete/cohesive [mcve] so it's overtly clear what exactly is being rendered and where/how they are rendered?